# Where's the Colorado River water going between Glen Canyon and Lake Mead?

Tags: hydrology, rivers

While looking through the ["minimum inflow" 24-month projection for the Colorado River basin](https://www.usbr.gov/lc/region/g4000/24mo_MIN.pdf), I noticed something odd for the Lake Mead chart: an expected negative inflow from side streams in June 2023.

```
Date      Glen release  Side inflow  Evap losses
Jun 2023  577           -13          44
```

Where's the water going?  It's not evaporating -- that's accounted for elsewhere.  As far as I know, the Colorado has no distributaries between Glen Canyon Dam and Lake Mead, and no significant users.  The ground should be pretty well saturated after spring runoff.  So what's happening to the 13,000 acre-feet (16,000 cubic meters) of water?

Comment: In June20**23**!! *Really*? It still 20**22**.

Comment: @Fred, yes.  This *is* a projection of water flows for the next 24 months, after all.

Comment: Suggest for the most clear answer, it may just be best to email the authors: nsantos@usbr.gov and hpatno@usbr.gov are the email addresses I found Googling.  And either invite them to answer here or repost their answers with permission, so we all have a better understanding (as I have no idea, it may take quite a bit of digging in through the details to understand exactly what the tables are showing, when they likely can quickly answer as they are experts on the topic)

Comment: Supplying Las Vegas?